# Communication fragments/activities

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my existing app I am porting two activities to fragments. The case is the classic dual panel mode with a list on the left and the content on the right.

The doc says that I should avoid to manipulate fragments within fragments, passing instead through the host activity. Said that I am using callbacks to the activity.

The first doubt (maybe banal) I have is:

> How to avoid to duplicate the same code in the activity that hosts the
>   2 fragments and into the activity that wraps the fragment when not in
>   dual mode?

I'll try to explain. So I have:

- ListFragment and ListFragmentActivity
- ContentFragment and ContentFragmentActivity

because both fragments can live independently from each other, then:

- HostActivity

that implements a listener invoked from ListFragment for adding/replacing the ContentFragment

> My question is: when ListFragment is instead hosted from ListFragmentActivity, how to avoid to duplicate the code present in the HostActivity into ListFragmentActivity.

Guess I am missing something, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of `ListFragmentActivity`. Have `HostActivity` handle the case where there is either one or both fragments. Then, by definition, there is no code duplication. See: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/LargeScreen/EU4You